# How to get auto-completion for meteor API working on Visual Studio?

Tags: meteor

I am new user of Meteor JS. I am using visual studio IDE but keyword,functions etc are not reflecting in this. How is it possible? Please give solution

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Meteor is all Javascript. There is good javscript IDE called [Jetbrains Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) which has good [support for Meteor](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/)

I highly recommend it

Comment: I'd like to add that I was skeptical at first but it is well worth it. It also is free for Open source projects and students. But 50 bucks is really not much for what it brings.

Comment: Thanks Ajduke, but i want do do this in Visual Studio. is this possible?

Comment: @SantoshVishwakarma Hi, i am not aware of any integration with Visual Studio. Meteor on Windows is still evolving, hope we will have some integration with VS sometime in near future

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** *This answer was written for the original question title"Which IDE is better for Meteor JS? ".*

This is by design a subjective question requesting a subjective answer. Here is one from my experience.

The best editor I found so far is [Atom](https://atom.io/), free, open-source, very customizable, and lots of very good plugins. And it is getting better everyday.

If you plan to give it a try, I would suggest to install at least the following plugins:

- minimap
- atom-bootstrap if you use bootstrap with meteor (snippets + autocompletion)
- linter for code validation
- merge-conflicts if you use git and sometimes have to deal with merging issues
- meteor-API for meteor autocompletion
- meteor helper for start/stop the server from atom
- meteor-snippets (I love this one) so you can create snippets easily, (i.e. is you type "temp" and enter, it generates all the base code (helpers & event) for a template.

If you look for the auto-indent function, there is a built-in one. You can add it a shortcut in your keymap by pasting this in it because by default there is none:

```
'.editor':
  'alt-a': 'editor:auto-indent'
```

I hope it helps.

ps: if someone has plugins suggestions, they are welcome

Comment: Thanks Billybobbonnet, to give this solution.

Comment: can we directly launch meteor app using atom?

Comment: Yes, there is a meteor package to achieve that. In Atom menu, go to packages > Settings view > Install packages/themes. Search for meteor and get all related packages. Btw, I mentionned it in my answer (meteor helper)